# Is there a function/package in R that can generate data where you can specify the relationship between variables?

Tags: r, regression, simulation, logistic-regression

I am interested in running some multivariable linear regression data simulations to try out some new statistical methods before I use them on my real dataset, where I regress a set of predictor variables on an outcome (both continuous and categorical).

The goal would be to generate data with three fake exposures, and an outcome, with the option of setting the beta estimate for the relationship between each exposure and outcome (continuous), or the relative risk or odds ratio for the outcome (categorical outcome). Is that something that can be easily done in R?

For example, it would be great to set a 4 variable dataset where one variable is related to the categorical outcome with an OR/RR of 1.5 that I set, and then I would get a RR/OR of 1.5 for that relationship if I ran a logistic regression on the dataset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random categorical variables and then set B0=1, B1=log(1.5), B2=1, B3=1, and generate the appropraite XB. Then using a logit link function, you can generate P(Y=1|x) for each observation/row x and use `sample` to choose Y=1 or 0 with that probability. Fit a logistic regression using the binomial family and finally exponentiate the coefficient of "a" to get the odds ratio for this variable. Since we had set it to log(1.5), exponentiating gives approximately 1.5.

```
dt=data.frame(a=sample(c(0,1), 10000, replace=TRUE), 
              b=sample(c(0,1), 10000, replace=TRUE),
              c=sample(c(0,1), 10000, replace=TRUE))
library(dplyr)
dt=mutate(dt, xb=1+log(1.5)*a+b+c, linked=1/(1+exp(-xb)))
y=numeric()
for (i in 1:10000) {
  y[i]=sample(c(1,0), prob=c(dt$linked[i], 1-dt$linked[i]), size=1)
}
dt$y=y
m=glm(data=dt, y ~ a+b+c, family="binomial")
exp(m$coef["a"])

1.422448
```